# Java REST WebService

Tags: java, rest, netbeans

I'm trying to build a Java REST web service that will do some processing on a get request (eg. send get request with info, do some calculations, then send back an object with the results). Any ideas how I can set this up easily in Netbeans? I've been playing with the New->RESTful web service... feature, but can't seem to get it to return an object.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you're supposed to return a string representation of the result. For example implementing the `getXml()` method:

```
/**
 * Retrieves representation of an instance of services.GenericResource
 * @return an instance of java.lang.String
 */
@GET
@Produces("application/xml")
public String getXml() {
    return "<entry></entry>";
}
```

You could use an XML API to turn your objects into XML strings and return them.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of object do you want to return...?
In java rest webservice you can return many kinds of objects like json,xml.

You can follow these tutorials for creating any kind of java rest webservice -
 http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/json-example-with-jersey-jackson/

This link shows example of get request which returns a json object. You can browse there tutorials for any other requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it in Netbeans, but I have done it using Intellij tho, using maven. Just used servlets to get the requests and used GSON to convert the outgoing java object to JSON and send it out.

[This is the project I did with some of my colleges.](https://github.com/JDPrabasha/Verdur/tree/main/Server)